# Understanding Django Pagination : Does it internally limit entries fetched?

Tags: django, comments

I am working on pagination of django comments.

```
def listing(request):
    contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
```

Does the paginator lead to fetching of 25 entries or does it fetch all and return only the required ones ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **When are QuerySets evaluated?**
>
> Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and generally passed around without
>   actually hitting the database. No database activity actually occurs
>   until you do something to evaluate the queryset.

source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated